# Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, spring-boot, cors

I am trying to connect my Angular Js code in one port to RESTFul service which is on another port. We are using spring boot.

I am getting this error:
-> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
-> GET http://localhost:8181/newControl 403 ().

We have tried everything by adding headers in angular js and also on the server side. Still unable to resolve the issue.

myController.js

```
$scope.getDataFromServer = function() {

    $http({
        method : 'GET',
        url : 'http://localhost:8181/newControl',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
} 
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Data is :");
        console.log(data);
        $scope.person = data;
        $scope.update();
        //$('#specializationId').find('select').trigger('change');
        //angular.element(e.target).siblings('#upload').trigger('click');
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
    });

};
```

NewController.java

```
@RestController
public class NewController {

@RequestMapping("/newController")
public String firstPage() {

    return ("Hello... Welcome to Springboot");
}

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8181")
@RequestMapping("/newControl")
public PersonData getPersonData(final HttpServletResponse response) {


    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");


    PersonData person = new PersonData();
    Adress address = new Adress();
    person.setFirstName("Adam");
    person.setLastName("hewad");
    address.setCity("XYZ");
    address.setCountry("ABC");
    address.setState("pqrs");
    person.setGender("Male");
    person.setSpecialization("Dev");
    person.setAddress(address);

    return person;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please replace all your `response.setHeaders..` with these => `response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials","true");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Set-Cookie");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, x-xsrf-token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Expires, Last-Modified, Cache-Control");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");`

Comment: @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8181") . This part of the code, isn't it suppose to have the port of the accessing web app? Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @Thiagz Right. It seems that should be `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")`

Comment: you have a content-type that triggers an CORS OPTIONS preflight - does the server handle such things?

Comment: Also, adding `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'` will guarantee a pre-flighted OPTIONS request because it's a "non standard" header - and in this regard shows a lack of understanding of which end of a CORS request grants access

Comment: @Thiagz and sideshowbarker .. It worked after changing the port to 8080. But can this be generic, that works for any URL...

Comment: Just leave it as @CrossOrigin. It can accept all origins